# Create dynamic events to javascript calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, fullcalendar

I have a  javascript calendar and I am trying to insert custom events on this from a json object. 
The code for the calendar and the default events is:

```
 /* initialize the calendar
             -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate(),
                    m = date.getMonth(),
                    y = date.getFullYear();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {//This is to add icons to the visible buttons
                    prev: "<span class='fa fa-caret-left'></span>",
                    next: "<span class='fa fa-caret-right'></span>",
                    today: 'today',
                    month: 'month',
                    week: 'week',
                    day: 'day'
                },
                //Random default events
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red 
                        borderColor: "#f56954" //red
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                        backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
                        borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
                        borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
                        borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
                        borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
                        borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
                    }
                ],
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
                    copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                }
            });

            /* ADDING EVENTS */
            var currColor = "#f56954"; //Red by default
            //Color chooser button
            var colorChooser = $("#color-chooser-btn");
            $("#color-chooser > li > a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Save color
                currColor = $(this).css("color");
                //Add color effect to button
                colorChooser
                        .css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor})
                        .html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            });
            $("#add-new-event").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get value and make sure it is not null
                var val = $("#new-event").val();
                if (val.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                //Create event
                var event = $("<div />");
                event.css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor, "color": "#fff"}).addClass("external-event");
                event.html(val);
                $('#external-events').prepend(event);

                //Add draggable functionality
                ini_events(event);

                //Remove event from text input
                $("#new-event").val("");
            });
```

In the code below I substitute the dummy events with my json object and I am trying with a for loop to create custom events. The object comes normally but the events are not represented on the calendar.

```
  /* initialize the calendar
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../services/myservice.asmx/mylist",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {






    //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)


    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        buttonText: {//This is to add icons to the visible buttons
            prev: "<span class='fa fa-caret-left'></span>",
            next: "<span class='fa fa-caret-right'></span>",
            today: 'today',
            month: 'month',
            week: 'week',
            day: 'day'
        },
        //There i substitute the dummy events with the real that comes from  json
        events: [function () {

            for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                {
                    title: (data.d[i].thetitle);
                    start: new Date(data.d[i].y, data.d[i].m, data.d[i].d, 12, 0);
                    end: new Date(data.d[i].y, data.d[i].m, data.d[i].d, 14, 0);
                    allDay: false;
                    backgroundColor: "#00c0ef"; //Info (aqua)
                    borderColor: "#00c0ef"; //Info (aqua)
                }

            }
        }],

        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
        drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
            var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
            copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
            copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }

        }
    });

    /* ADDING EVENTS */
    var currColor = "#f56954"; //Red by default
    //Color chooser button
    var colorChooser = $("#color-chooser-btn");
    $("#color-chooser > li > a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Save color
        currColor = $(this).css("color");
        //Add color effect to button
        colorChooser
                .css({ "background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor })
                .html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
    $("#add-new-event").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get value and make sure it is not null
        var val = $("#new-event").val();
        if (val.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        //Create event
        var event = $("<div />");
        event.css({ "background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor, "color": "#fff" }).addClass("external-event");
        event.html(val);
        $('#external-events').prepend(event);

        //Add draggable functionality
        ini_events(event);

        //Remove event from text input
        $("#new-event").val("");
    });
   }
    });
```

EDIT. I iam posting the original template of the calendar that i am trying to use

```
   <!-- THE CALENDAR -->
                                <div id="calendar"></div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                        </div><!-- /. box -->
                    </div><!-- /.col -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->  


            </section><!-- /.content -->
        </aside><!-- /.right-side -->
    </div><!-- ./wrapper -->


    <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI 1.10.3 -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="../js/AdminLTE/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- fullCalendar -->
    <script src="../js/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Page specific script -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            /* initialize the external events
             -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            function ini_events(ele) {
                ele.each(function() {

                    // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
                    // it doesn't need to have a start or end
                    var eventObject = {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text()) // use the element's text as the event title
                    };

                    // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
                    $(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 1070,
                        revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });

                });
            }
            ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));

            /* initialize the calendar
             -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
            //Date for the calendar events (dummy data)
            var date = new Date();
            var d = date.getDate(),
                    m = date.getMonth(),
                    y = date.getFullYear();
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                buttonText: {//This is to add icons to the visible buttons
                    prev: "<span class='fa fa-caret-left'></span>",
                    next: "<span class='fa fa-caret-right'></span>",
                    today: 'today',
                    month: 'month',
                    week: 'week',
                    day: 'day'
                },
                //Random default events
                events: [
                    {
                        title: 'All Day Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                        backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red 
                        borderColor: "#f56954" //red
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Long Event',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
                        backgroundColor: "#f39c12", //yellow
                        borderColor: "#f39c12" //yellow
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Meeting',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#0073b7", //Blue
                        borderColor: "#0073b7" //Blue
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Lunch',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00c0ef", //Info (aqua)
                        borderColor: "#00c0ef" //Info (aqua)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Birthday Party',
                        start: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 19, 0),
                        end: new Date(y, m, d + 1, 22, 30),
                        allDay: false,
                        backgroundColor: "#00a65a", //Success (green)
                        borderColor: "#00a65a" //Success (green)
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Click for Google',
                        start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                        end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                        url: 'http://google.com/',
                        backgroundColor: "#3c8dbc", //Primary (light-blue)
                        borderColor: "#3c8dbc" //Primary (light-blue)
                    }
                ],
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
                drop: function(date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                    // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                    var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                    // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                    var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                    // assign it the date that was reported
                    copiedEventObject.start = date;
                    copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                    copiedEventObject.backgroundColor = $(this).css("background-color");
                    copiedEventObject.borderColor = $(this).css("border-color");

                    // render the event on the calendar
                    // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                }
            });

            /* ADDING EVENTS */
            var currColor = "#f56954"; //Red by default
            //Color chooser button
            var colorChooser = $("#color-chooser-btn");
            $("#color-chooser > li > a").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Save color
                currColor = $(this).css("color");
                //Add color effect to button
                colorChooser
                        .css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor})
                        .html($(this).text()+' <span class="caret"></span>');
            });
            $("#add-new-event").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                //Get value and make sure it is not null
                var val = $("#new-event").val();
                if (val.length == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                //Create event
                var event = $("<div />");
                event.css({"background-color": currColor, "border-color": currColor, "color": "#fff"}).addClass("external-event");
                event.html(val);
                $('#external-events').prepend(event);

                //Add draggable functionality
                ini_events(event);

                //Remove event from text input
                $("#new-event").val("");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: if you mean this plugin [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar), then you are not correctly fill events object, try see [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/), and [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) and [this](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_array/)

Comment: @Grundy none of your links work anymore

Comment: @Liza, yep, 8 years is 8 years :-) [events_function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/events-function), [json feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/events-json-feed), [array](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/events-array)

Answer (score 0):

You can render your calendar first and then add events after the data has been loaded.  You have a number of errors in your event definition.  You can't have semi-colons in it, you must use commas to separate the properties.  In your ajax success function.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   //your calendar definition here
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../services/myservice.asmx/mylist",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",

    success: function(data) {
      #remove any events that have been loaded
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');

      for (i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) { 
        var the_event = {
          title: (data.d[i].thetitle),
          start: new Date(data.d[i].y, data.d[i].m, data.d[i].d, 12, 0),
          end: new Date(data.d[i].y, data.d[i].m, data.d[i].d, 14, 0),
          allDay: false,
          backgroundColor: "#00c0ef",
          borderColor: "#00c0ef",    
        }
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',the_event,true);
      }
    }
});
```

What this does is loop through the data returned and creates a new event object that then gets added to the calendar using the renderEvent method.  I added removeEvents only as an example. THis would only be necessary if the ajax call returns a completely new set of events.

Comment: How can i add the calendar definition first and then add the events? Also how can i remove the events that initially has been added from the full callendar template? I have edit my post and provide you the full code of the calendar that i am using.It has also template events.

Comment: can you be more specific on what are you suggesting me?

Comment: Basically, I'm am suggesting that you define your calendar, the code for which I didn't include.  Once your calendar has been defined, you can add any events you want using ajax.  To remove any events already in your calendar, use `$('calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents')`.

Comment: What errors are you getting in the javascript console? Did you separate the calendar definition and the loading of the events?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching your events with an AJAX request, you should use the ability of fullCalendar to automatically fetch data based on an URL:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  //...
  events: {
    url: '../services/myservice.asmx/mylist'
  }
});
```

With this, all your data will be synced, and you can still remove with `.fullCalendar('removeEvents');` or refresh any changes with `.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');`.

Here's a working JSBin where I added two buttons for removing and refreshing examples:

http://jsbin.com/binaf/1/